# How to maximize window top/bottom half screen in Gnome?

Tags: gnome-shell, mutter, maximize

Does somebody knows how to maximize a window to the half top or half bottom of a screen in gnome?

I have found only how to do it left/right, but not top/bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutter` doesn't support that yet...
You can snap to top/bottom if you install the [`ShellTile`](https://github.com/emasab/shelltile) extension.
More details on their home page.
Depending on your setup, you may need to disable the default edge tiling for this to work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling false
```

and/or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
```

Comment: I just tested it and works like a charm! Thanks @don_crissti